# Как проверить число на четность?

Tags: python, числа

Понимаю, что надо делить на 2 и смотреть на остаток. Вот что пытался делать.

```
if ( not line%2 ):
    print 'chek true'
```

Answer (score 11):

Возможен и такой вариант:

```
for x in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4):
    if not x & 1: 
        print "%d is even" % x
```

Answer (score 9):

```
for x in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4):
    if x % 2 == 0: 
        print "%d is even" % x
```

http://ideone.com/2WMaT

Если нужна не четность, а нечетность - соответственно,  `x % 2 != 0`.

Comment: Говорить
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Несоответствие типов что ли, да?

Comment: Я так понял, это уже речь о некой модификации моего примера? Тогда, пожалуйста, код в студию -  телепаты в отпуске. Приведенная ошибка появляется если в строке было одно число плейсхолдеров (%d и иже с ним), а справа оператору `%` передали меньше.

Comment: Похоже, догадался о чем речь. Если на `x % 2`  оно так ругается, то x - строка, так что, да, проблема в типах. Для них оператор `%`  имеет другой, не связаный с остатком от деления, смысл.

Answer (score 3):

```
def checker(number):
    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number % 2 == 1:
            print('непарное')
        if number % 2 == 0:
            print('парное')
    except:
        print('этот символ не номер')

checker(8)
```

Comment: А как же отрицательные числа?

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(000000, 1000000000):
  if x % 2 == 0:
    print(Chet)
  else:
    print(Nechet)
```

Comment: Насчёт минуса не беспокойтесь, он дан автоматом потому, что код был не отформатирован. А где определены Chet и Nechet?

Answer (score -3):

```
number = int(input("Введите число: "))
if (number%2 == 0):
  print("Четное число")
else:
  print("Нечетное число")
```

Comment: Чем ваше решение лучше уже существующих тут более пяти лет? Поставил воспитательный минус.

Comment: @AK, это единственный работающий вариант среди 5 данных начиная с 2017 года... Вполне заслуживает плюсик.

Answer (score -3):

```
number = int(input("Введите число: "))
if (number/2):
    print("Четное число")
else:
    print("Нечетное число")
```

Comment: Фигня какая-то...

Answer (score -6):

```
number = int(input("Введите число: "))
if (number%2 > 0):
  print("Не чётное число =(")
else:
  print(number+2)
```

Comment: Чем ваше решение лучше уже существующих тут более пяти лет?

Comment: Почему `> 0`, а не `== 1` / `!= 0`? Почему `print(number+2)`?

Comment: А отрицательные числа что, чётные?